# Convert String to Date time C# Error String was not recognize

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, c#-4.0, datetime

I am trying to convert string to date time. My textbox contains a date only. My code is:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtEOIDate.Text))
{
    DateTime dt; 
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEOIDate.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
    invProject.created = dt;
}
```

**txtEOIDate.Text** contains "8/22/2014"

"invproject" is class object have datetime field "created"

error is `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

on line

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEOIDate.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
```

I am using framework 4.0

UPDATE ANSWER:

Solution which work for me is:

```
string tes = txtEOIDate.Text.ToString().Trim();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(tes.Split('/')[2]), Convert.ToInt16(tes.Split('/')[0]), Convert.ToInt16( tes.Split('/')[1]));
invProject.created = dt;
```

Comment: *my textbox contain date only my code is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt`* "My textbox contains text in a format and I say parse something that's not this format and it's not working why internets helpline why isn't it working"

Comment: Because using ParseExact needs to match the datetime format exactly, as described on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Kindly check solution

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEOIDate.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
```

To this:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEOIDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
```

If you are using the standard textbox then `txtEOIDate.ToString()` is equals to:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

Not:

```
8/22/2014
```

**Update**

If you want to parse a date which is in the format `M/dd/yyyy`. Why not just put it in the `ParseExact`. Like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtEOIDate.Text,"M/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I think this is just one problem. The documentation for `ParseExact` says *The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.*

Comment: still getting this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need ParseExact?

You cannot use ParseExact since you are not submitting all the values (hours, minutes etc.) I would do like this:

```
    var dt = DateTime.Parse(txtEOIDate.Text);
```

**UPDATE**
This works:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtEOIDate.Text))
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Parse(this.txtEOIDate.Text);
            invProject.created = dt;
        }
```

Comment: i used it it gave me error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: It works for me, can you verify that txtEOIDate.Text is equal to "8/22/2014" ?

Comment: I am sure it must work as it was working for me before but all of a sudden i am getting this error on this code dont know why and i am getting "8/22/2014" in  tstEOIDate this is for sure

Comment: txtEOIDate is the textbox I would presume, you should use txtEOIDate.Text, the problem you are experiencing is because you seem to not be able to keep track of what types you are submitting as parameters to the Parse method. The Parse method accepts a string parameter which, if it looks like "8/22/2014" - it will work.

Comment: you are right this code must work i am unable to understand why i am getting this error and txtEOIDate is the textbox

Answer (score 0):

`txtEOIDate.ToString()` does not return the Text of `txtEOIDate`
you should to change it to `txtEOIDate.Text` ...

and

change `FormatString` from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt` to `M/dd/yyyy`

Comment: i have used .text as well as .tostring

Comment: change `FormatString` from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt` to `M/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you are actually using txtEOIDate.Text, not txtEOIDate.ToString(). Secondly, I personally would use TryParse like this:

```
DateTime MyNewDT;
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtEOIDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out MyNewDT);
```

The format you input is not what you want it to be in but what format the string is currently in. As such, you are creating a DateTime variable that you can use.